# Вывод в список переменных, пронумерованных по порядку, в которых содержатся данные

Tags: python

Есть переменные. Пытаюсь вывести в файл Microsoft Word пронумерованный список по порядку переменных, в которых содержатся данные. Вывод

```
 1. Привет 
 4. 38000
```

А надо

```
1. Привет 
2. 38000
```

Подскажите как это сделать
Делаю так

```
a = 'Привет'
b = None
c = none
d = 38000

variable_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
doc.add_heading('Variables with values', level=1)
for i, var_name in enumerate(variable_names):
    var_value = globals()[var_name]
    if var_value is not None:
        i = 0

        doc.add_paragraph(f"{i +1}. {var_value}")

# Save the document
doc.save('output.docx')
```

Comment: Зачем `globals`? Если вы завели список имён переменных, почему не хранить их значения в словаре?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придётся считать "вручную":

```py
i = 1
for var_name in variable_names:
    var_value = globals()[var_name]
    if var_value is not None:
        doc.add_paragraph(f"{i}. {var_value}")
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = {
    'a': 'Привет',
    'b': None,
    'c': None,
    'd': 38000
}

doc.add_heading('Variables with values', level=1)
for i, v in enumerate((v for v in values.values() if v is not None), start=1):
    doc.add_paragraph(f'{i}. {v}')
```